# Same value on all models -> Collection event

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, collections, models

Is it possible to have a Backbone Collection trigger an event when all the models in it have the same value assigned to a parameter?

For example all the models in a collection may start with :

```
model.value = false;
```

And i want the collection to trigger an event when all the models have

```
model.value = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default backbone does not provide this as a feature, however you could check if all the models have the same attribute and then trigger a custom event.

```
if(this.collection.length === this.collection.where({value: true}).length)
{
   this.collection.trigger('synchronized');
}
```

You would have to do this check each time you changed the "value" attribute.

Comment: Great, i'll stop looking then. Thank you for that snippet tho, a lot cleaner then what i produced.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible approach:

```
// Model
var m = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.on("change", this.publish)
    },

    publish: function(){
        this.trigger("changed");
    }

});

// Collection
var c = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: m,

    initialize: function(){
        this.on("changed", this.check);
    },

    check: function(){
        console.log(this.length === this.where({value: true}).length);
    }

});

var m1 = new m();
var m2 = new m();

var c1 = new c([m1, m2]);

m1.set("value", true);
m2.set("value", true);
```